# Having issues with my Discord bot not responding to prompts

Tags: python, discord, chatbot

Code Base:

```
import os
import json
import time
import sys
import discord
import aiohttp
import random
import datetime
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from bot_framework import BotFramework

# create an instance of commands.Bot with the desired command prefix and intents
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~', intents=discord.Intents.default())

# load the cogs
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    # check that the file is a Python file and not a hidden file
    if filename.endswith('.py') and not filename.startswith('__'):
        # load the cog
        bot.load_extension('cogs.Bchat')
        bot.load_extension('cogs.Bgifs')
        bot.load_extension('cogs.Bmemes')

# event handler for when the bot has successfully connected to Discord
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}')
    # set the bot's presence
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='~help'))

# event handler for when a command fails to execute properly
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    # check if the error is a CommandNotFound error
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        # if so, send a message letting the user know the command was not found
        await ctx.send('Command not found. Use ~help to see available commands.')
    else:
        # if it's any other error, print the error to the console
        print(error)

# run the bot with the provided token
bot.run('KEY')
```

I was using this code as a base for my Discord bot to load in some supplemental cogs for things like GIFS , basic chat stuff etc.

I tried implementing intents , ( seen on line 14 ) but now it isnt responding to tilde ~ . Not sure why, any help would be appreciated!

Tried reverting back to old version of bot

Tried adjusting intents declaration

Comment: Your bot can't read messages without the messages intent, which is not included in the default intents you're supplying.

Answer (score 1):

i see one big problem here:

```py
# load the cogs
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    # check that the file is a Python file and not a hidden file
    if filename.endswith('.py') and not filename.startswith('__'):
        # load the cog
        bot.load_extension('cogs.Bchat')
        bot.load_extension('cogs.Bgifs')
        bot.load_extension('cogs.Bmemes')
```

what is this for a random check and loop? this will load some static cogs for every file that ends with py in a directory?
doesnt make really sense.

if you want to load all cogs in the directory if they dont start with __
make soemthing like

```py
# load the cogs
for filename in os.listdir('cogs'):
    # check that the file is a Python file and not a hidden file
    if filename.endswith('.py') and not filename.startswith('__'):
        # load the cog
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

or just load the cogs static